# How to add slider in typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am new in Typo3. I want to make slider dynamic in my Typo3 setup. The current version installed is 9.5.3. It will be better if I could get all the sections that is mentioned in this article http://www.typo3manual.com/typo3-version-8/52-content-elements/17-slider/. You can also see the screenshot attached. But I think the article was for version 8 and mine is 9.5. Is there any way that I could get all sections that is mentioned in screenshot?

[image]

Comment: That content element is not part of the TYPO3 Core; it has been added using a third-party extension; maybe EXT:bootstrap_package?

Comment: you can always of course create your own content elements

Answer (score 0):

These content elements are part of the "T3Kit" website starter kit (basically just an extension). You can find a great tutorial here: http://www.typo3manual.com/typo3-version-8/52-content-elements/ , or on their official website: http://www.t3kit.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many slider extension available. You can install it and can override its template.

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/owl_slider/